# flutter como hacer un select where con sqflite?

Tags: android, sql, flutter, dart, sqflite

Estoy comenzando a manejar sqflite, tengo una archivo databaseHelper.dart que es donde creo las inserciones a la bd por unica vez. Y tengo las demás screens que muestra listado de items y el contenido de dichos items.

Como puedo hacer un select where dentro del codigo de dart? Debo hacer en databaseHelper o puedo hacerlo dentro de cada screen?

Mi intención es crear otra nueva screen que se muestre solo los items que cumplan con ciertas caracteristicas.

mi dbhelper:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'lista_model.dart';

class DatabaseHandler {
  Future<Database> initializeDB() async {
    String path = await getDatabasesPath();
    return openDatabase(
      join(path, 'courses1.db'), //join(path, 'tododatabase.db'),
      onCreate: (database, version) async {
        final String sql = ''
            'CREATE TABLE todos ('
            ' id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'
            ' title TEXT,'
            ' entidad TEXT,'
            ' categoria TEXT,'
            ' emision TEXT,'
            ' imgco TEXT,'
            ' urlco TEXT,'
            ' descrip TEXT'
            ')';

        await database.execute(sql);

        final String addCourse = ''
            'INSERT INTO todos(title, entidad, categoria, emision, imgco, urlco, descrip) VALUES (' ...
```

en las screen donde muestro los items en lista, uso `FutureBuilder<List<todo>>` para hacer un snapshot y presentar todos los inserts.

Y para entrar al contenido de cada item de lista, solo paso como argumento el objeto index tipo `'todo'` a la otra screen y los leo con el `objeto.title, objeto.entidad` etc...

Como podria filtrar enonces la tabla con un select where en codigo sql o de otra forma dentro de la screen que quiero?

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo primero cambiar un poco la estrutura de tu `base de datos` para poder declara una `instancia` de la misma y poder acceder a ella desde otro lado.

```
    class DatabaseHandler {
       DatabaseHandler.internal();
  static final  DatabaseHandler instance =  DatabaseHandler.internal();
  factory  DatabaseHandler() => instance;

  static Database? _database;

  static Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;

    _database = await initDB();
    return _database!;
  }

      static initDB() async {
        String path = await getDatabasesPath();
        return openDatabase(
          join(path, 'courses1.db'), //join(path, 'tododatabase.db'),
          onCreate: (database, version) async {
            final String sql = ''
                'CREATE TABLE todos ('
                ' id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'
                ' title TEXT,'
                ' entidad TEXT,'
                ' categoria TEXT,'
                ' emision TEXT,'
                ' imgco TEXT,'
                ' urlco TEXT,'
                ' descrip TEXT'
                ')';
    
            await database.execute(sql);
    
            final String addCourse = ''
                'INSERT INTO todos(title, entidad, categoria, emision, imgco, urlco, descrip) VALUES (' ...
```

Podrías crear una función dentro de la clase o screen algo tal que así:

```
 Future<dynamic> obtenerLista() async {
        final db = await DatabaseHandler.database;
        
        final listTodo = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM todos 
        WHERE id LIKE 1");

        return listInfPerson;
      }
```

Ya despues de esto puedes llamar a esta función en tu `ListView.builder`.

Si sigues esos pasos ya podrías acceder a la instancia de la `clase` `DatabaseHandler` para poder realizar un `Query` en otra clase.